# How to edit .env file after build completed reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i had build react app web page 
with custom environment variables
the problem is when i build the script 
and change the .env variables no thing change in the website !

`.env` file :

`REACT_APP_SITENAME=TheSiteName App`

Comment: Why do you want to change it after the build?

Comment: @Mihai because i want to sell the script and how buy it can change and customize the app :D

Comment: When you change the .env file, you will need to rebuild it for the changes to apply.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After building a react app all code is static and can't be changed. I think the only solution to send some dynamic data to your react app is to either create a special file per system you running your app on and load this directly inside the index.html or create the content of this file on the fly.
So when you're using create-react-app in public/index.html add something like this:

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://www.example.com/envconfig.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
...
</head>
```

This file should contain the environmental config, e.g.:

```
window.globalConfig = {
    siteName: "The Sitename App"
}
```

The file can also be created on the fly by PHP, Java or any other backend service. Just make sure to answer as valid Javascript.

And in your React app at index.js, App.js or anywhere you can access this variable as it is global:

```
   const appConfig = window.globalConfig || { siteName: process.env.REACT_APP_SITENAME}
```

With this you've got an fallback to the static env config if `globalConfig` is not available, likely in development.
Now you can use appConfig in any way and provide it via redux, context or property to your components.

Last thing to mention, you have to make sure that the config-file is loaded before executing all the React code. So the file should be loaded before all the created React files.

Comment: Note that the script tag should be closed by it's end tag "</script>" instead of using the self-closing version. Without it this solution does not work correctly in Chrome.

Comment: @martinnemec3 You are right, thanks for mentioning. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 3):

here is an idea:

1. add a json file (e.a. config.json) with your configuration to the "public" folder. That file will be in the root of the build:

> {
> "name": "value" }

2. in your React code, create a static class with the variable you want to configure:

> class Config {
> static name= "[default value overwritten by the config]"; }

3. somewhere high in the startup of your React application, read the json and set the static variable:

> fetch("config.json")  .then((r) => r.json())  .then((data) =>{
> Config.name=data.name; })

4. now you can use that config anywhere you need it :

> Config.name

Note that any configuration you make will be vulnerable for public eyes, since the file can be opened directly with a URL. Also note that when deleting that json file, everything will still work with the default value. You could implement some check that the file must exist.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from the docs:

> The environment variables are embedded during the build time.

It isn't possible to apply environment changes as runtime.

[Reference](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables)

Here is an example of how to use the environment at runtime:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/m3ol8p19x8)

Comment: thank you ,is there is any way to config and customize the app after build ?

Comment: Only through the use of JavaScript at runtime. This is not Java if that is your background.

Comment: My background is php :D  .. How can i do it ? like fetching sitename or site logo image url from json and putting it in reactjs

Comment: No longer accepted answer? Why? How can I help further?

Comment: thank you for your time , how can i config the website after build :( like the sitename or any think

Comment: Did you see the CodeSandbox I provided in the answer?

Comment: i see it yes .but when change the env file after build no thing will be changed :( ..this sandbox is not a build right?

Comment: @TawfekMohammed "like fetching sitename or site logo image url from json and putting it in reactjs" That is one solution. Another solution is to rebuild the script each time you change the `.env` file.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you very much for your time see the accepted anwer 