# Reactjs : set .env file with 3 variables(prod,dev,staging) in the build folder with react build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, dotenv

I have a react app with build folder ( generated by : npm run build ) , I want to have 3 variables in my .env file ( just one file ):

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api ( for production)
REACT_APP_PROD_URL=http://localhost:3001/api ( for staging)
REACT_APP_STAGIN_URL=http://localhost:3002/api ( for development)
```

and use them in the npm run build folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate .env file for each environment.

As said in [CRA Documentation: What other .env files can be used?](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used):

> .env.development, .env.test, .env.production: Environment-specific settings.

You can't place all your env variables in one file, the values will be overridden. For more information check [`dotenv` documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Or if you want to edit env variables after building your project, please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56120507/5078746

Comment: I can't have 3 var and each variables has it's own name ? and I test if node_env==prod I call the production url .. ?

Comment: You can't do it in the same file, it will be overridden at it will take the last value for that variable. You either go for the suggested solution by having multiple `.env` files or create a file where you read your variables and apply your logic (`node_env==prod`...)

Answer (score 8):

- Create differences env files
- install `yarn add env-cmd`
- and add script to `package.json`:

`"start-qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts start"`

or build:

`"build-qa": "env-cmd -f .env.qa react-scripts build"`

Answer (score 3):

try with [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

something like this in your package.json

```
"start":  cross-env REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/api node scripts/start.js
```

may be it will help you in achieving your stuff